# Subsetting from one data frame based on multiple rows of another data frame

Tags: r, loops, date, filter, subset

I am working with acceleromater data from an actigraphy watch and I am trying to subset the periods in which a person is sleeping according to an algorithm. 
I have identified the periods in which a person is sleeping with the start and end point being in a seperate data frame then my original data. I am now trying to filter out the data between the point where a person goes to sleep and wakes up.

I have managed to write an filter for the first column, i.e. the first night but I don't quite know how to expand it to the other days.

`Data[Data$timestamp %in% Sleep$in_bed_time:Sleep$out_bed_time,] -> Data_sleep`

The timestamps look like this: 2020-01-23 23:22:07

I tried working with `for` and use ncol to expand the function till the last row of the dataframe Sleep, where the in and out of bedtimes are stored.

Thanks in advance!

*Edit: I have found a way around it, still I'd like to know how to expand the filter specified above, which only takes the first row of the column in Sleep$in_bed_time into account to the other rows.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a shortcut which I am gonna post for everyone running into the same problem:

If there is a column in which non-wear/wear periods or sleep/no-sleep periods are specified, one can use `actigraph.sleepr::combine_epochs_periods` to mark these periods. The first sleep period will then be marked wiht a "1" in an additional column so on. All other non sleep-columns will include NA, which one can simply exclude via `na.omit`

Answer (score 0):

You could try combing the in and out values with `c()` which is close to your approach.

```
Data[Data$timestamp %in% c(Sleep$in_bed_time,Sleep$out_bed_time),] -> Data_sleep
```

Or you could check in both columns and use the `|` OR logical operator.

```
Data[Data$timestamp %in% Sleep$in_bed_time | Data$timestamp %in% Sleep$out_bed_time,] -> Data_sleep
```

Comment: Hey there,  | is not suitable according to R and with c() I get a dataframe with twice the amount of columns of Sleep, containing only the data with equal time stamps.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not able to figure out what your expected output is then. Please provide samples of `Data` and `Sleep` with `dput()`.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not allowed to - but I can explain it further! The dataframe Data would contain timestamps as well as the actual data such as movement etc. One variable there is the time stamp and the actigraph watch produces data every 10 seconds. Within the dataframe Sleep there are now two variable, Sleep$in_bed_time and Sleep$out_bed_time and since I want the data between those points I used ":". I know how to filter it out one time, but I am looking for a way to subset it up to 21 times, for 21 nights.